# Node.js Modules aren't executing?

Tags: node.js, module

The modules that are normally installed via npm suddenly stopped working.
No errors are produced, the modules are bieng imported, but they're callback functions aren't being executed. I installed some softwares and maybe edited my system environment variables previously; to which is the reason they might not be working, but i'm unsure on how to solve this problem.
Any solutions or techniques in order to figure out or solve the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't provide enough information to understand the issue: "they're callback functions aren't being executed" - is totally unclear, please specify which modules and which callbacks. Also "maybe edited my system environment variables" is not helpful - which variables do you suspect you changed? (try to see your command history if possible). With this small amount of information I don't think anyone willbe able to help you!

Comment: Okay, sorry for being unclear, any modules that are required and imported in the top of my script; when I use console.log to see if the modules have been loaded, they come up correctly. When it comes time to execute the functions, example: method wrappers in express (app.get(), app.post()) they don't execute. Even http.createServer(f(req,res)) doesn't execute.
I'm not sure why they aren't executing but they haven't been executing after installing commands like composer, v8 engine, and so forth.

Comment: Is it a specific problem with express, or with other modules as well? did you try to delete `node_module` folder and run `npm install` and run your project?

Comment: I tried reinstalling the modules via npm. Haven't tried deleting my node_modules folder and reinstalling the modules after.

Comment: Just tried reinstallling the modules after deleting the node_modules folder, and it didn't work man.

Comment: I think I have to reformat my computer. >_> 
<_< I CANT THINK OF ANY SOLUTION.